# Ejecutar script para formatear discos desde php

Tags: php, linux, script

Tengo un script en linux que es para formatear discos duros.Quiero ejecutar dicho script desde php y tengo esto :

```
$dded = shell_exec('sh /var/www/proyecto/prueba.sh');
```

mi script es:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo 'Contrasena' | sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb1
```

Creo que es tema de permisos, si creo otro script con un mkdir si funciona bien.

Answer (score 0):

Para que no pida password sudo la sintaxis es la siguiente:

> nombreusuario ALL=(root) NOPASSWD:  /usr/sbin/mkfs.xfs

Al ejecutar sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb1 ya no te pide password